# Optional match group at the start of a regex always empty

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `asd@12A/AXB25017/12A@£££` which I want to extract `12A/AXB25017/12A` from.

I have designed a regexp pattern as following

```
'.*(([A-Z0-9]+/)?[A-Z]{3}\d+(/[A-Z0-9]+)?)'
```

Because I can have many different string variations. Valid string variations with different letters and numbers which I want to extract can be.

```
1) AXB25017
2) 1/AXB25017
3) AXB25017/1
4) 1A/AXB25017
5) AXB25017/1A
6) EN/AXB25017
7) EN/AXB25017/1
```

When I do

```
 re.match('.*(([A-Z0-9]+/)?[A-Z]{3}\d+(/[A-Z0-9]+)?)','  @12A/AXB25017/12A@').group(1)
```

It does not find the initial `12A/` but returns `AXB25017/12A`

What am I missing in my pattern to correctly catch `12A/` as well?

Comment: Remove `.*` and use `re.search`

Comment: What about `@(.+?)@` ? Do you have other delimiters? What is the rule here?

Comment: There are no other rules, only / is allowed as shown in the examples, everything else is noise,

Comment: `[A-Z0-9]+/` is valid to match as part of `.*`, so it's perfectly legal for the engine to put there. Make it `.*?` and at least you'd be instructing it to not be greedy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first optional part in your regex  `([A-Z0-9]+/)?` does not match, because ...

- it is optional
- the preceding 'match all' subexpression matches greedily

Include the delimiters in the regex:

```
.*\@(([A-Z0-9]+/)?[A-Z]{3}\d+(/[A-Z0-9]+)?)
```

If there is a possibility of material trailing the second delimiter, add that to the regex ...

```
.*\@(([A-Z0-9]+/)?[A-Z]{3}\d+(/[A-Z0-9]+)?)\@
```

... which might allow for a drastic simplification:

```
\@[^@]+\@
```

Comment: The problem is that it can be various type of garbage string before and after the substring of interest.

Comment: If you can identify say 'anchor' elements (words or chars, like `@` in your example) that are guaranteed to occur before and after the section with the substring of interest, you have the option to extract  the intervening string and remove the garbage using string functions or more regexen.